# Como obtener el texto de una etiqueta HTML con simple_html_dom.php

Tags: php, html, laravel

estoy tratando de sacar el texto que contienen determinadas etiquetas dentro del HTML en una pagina, estoy usando html_simple_dom.php que me ha parecido bueno para esto. Sin mas les dejo un ejemplo de mi problema.

Esta es la funcion en php

```
<?php
```

require('simple_html_dom.php');

```
function precioExito($url){
    $html = new simple_html_dom();
    $html->load_file($url); //Se carga la URL con la libreria
    $posts = $html->find('p[class=price offer]'); //Guardamos en Posts el precio que esta en span:price-number
    foreach($posts as $post) {  //Devuelve un array se recorre con el for para imprimir, como es unico valor, solo imprime 1
        $resultado = str_replace ( ".0", '', $post);

        break;
    }
    return $resultado;
  }
```

?>

Lo que hago es que llamo esta función si le hago un **echo** a ese valor, que me debe retorna me muestra por pantalla el valor (ver imagen)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Pero cuando ese valor que me retorna lo mando a la BD, esto es lo que me guarda en la BD. (Ver imagen)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pueden ver me esta trayendo toda la etiqueta HTML y no solo el valor.

PREGUNTA

¿Como puedo obtener solo el valor de esta etiqueta para poder guardarlo?

Muchas gracias.
Espero haber sido claro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si siempre va a querer obtener un único resultado te puedes ahorrar el foreach

Ejemplo:

```
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load_file($url);
$post = $html->find('p[class=price offer]', 0)->plaintext;
```

Con `->plaintext` extraemos el texto. Y con el segundo parámetro en `find()` indicamos el número del elemento a ser traído.

Comment: Muchas gracias, justo lo que necesitaba. Saludos Xerif

Answer (score 1):

Tu sistema hace eso porque aquí:

```
$posts = $html->find('p[class=price offer]');
```

Parece estás extrayendo toda la etiqueta, no el valor que contiene la etiqueta.

¿Por que en vez de extraer la clase mejor extraes el valor del id de la etiqueta?

Desconozco si lo que usas sea una biblioteca para extraer valores o una función programada por ti. No lo mencionas.

Aquí te dejo algo que te podría servir:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3249619/how-to-extract-a-value-of-an-html-input-tag-using-php

http://php.net/manual/es/language.variables.external.php

Comment: Gracias Pagana me ha servido los links para documentarme un poco mas acerca de esta libreria.